# Are there alternatives to “le mien”?

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs, possessif

Which one is correct?

1. celui do moi, or
2. celui de mien

Or is it more correct to just use "le mien" instead?

Comment: Both are incorrect. "Le mien" is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Celui* usually means "this one", "that one", or "the one".

> Celui que j'aime, c'est le bleu. *The blue one is the one I like.*

It is often suffixed with *-ci* to specify "this" or *-là* to specify "that".

> - Quel jouet veux-tu ? *Which toy do you want?*
>     
>   - Celui-ci ... le crocodile. *This one... the crocodile.*
>     
>   - Pas celui-là, le joli ours ? *Not that one, the nice bear?*
>     
>   - Pas du tout, maman ! *No way, mom!*

The way you worded it would mean something like "the one of mine", which is equally impossible in English and French. If you mean "mine", the one you want is *le mien*.